# CSS3 PIE Issue(s) with loading properly

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

I've uploaded the .htc file to my S3 CDN which did not seem to load at all. Then, I proceeded to uploading the .htc file to the same web server as the domain the document is running on, linked it properly and implemented the behavior CSS the way I've done it for previous shims in the past. However, the border-radius input boxes are not re-rendering within IE(8). Can any provide any insight to why this is not working properly?

Please view **https://give.massgeneral.org/bootstrap/sslpage.aspx?pid=2045** and view the CSS properties for any of the input boxes within the Donation form.

It appears that once the script is loaded, the boxes disappear within IE8. The script appears to be loading properly, so I'm not sure where the "hiccup" is.

Thanks ahead of time for any help/assistance provided.

> **This question is in relation to the one I left last Friday on the
>   developers support forums, which I have yet to receive a response for
>   http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2033**

Answer (score 0):

It appears, after further review and troubleshooting, that the issue was with the elements not being positioned relatively that are inheriting the behavior(PIE.htc).

> **Please refer to:** http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/